# Capturing values from file in array

Tags: arrays, histogram

I have the following code that reads numbers from a file and then prints asterisks for however many occurrences of the numbers there are within 10-digit ranges. The issue is with my for loop that adds the numbers to the array. Whenever I execute the code, it prints the last number (22) in the file 20 times and lists one asterisk in the 21-30 string. I'm sure this has to be a simple order issue. What am I missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class histogram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        final File numbers = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner filescan = new Scanner(numbers);

        int[] list = new int[101];


        while (filescan.hasNext()) {
            int num = filescan.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
            list[i] = num;

        }

        for(int value : list)
            System.out.println(value);

        String[] Stars = {"1-10 |", "11-20 |", "21-30 |", "31-40 |", "41-50 |", "51-60 |", "61-70 |", "71-80 |", "81-90 |", "91-100 |"};

        int number = 0;
        for (int st = 0; st < 101; st++)
            number = list[st];
        if (number < 11)
            Stars[0] += "*";
        else if (number < 21)
            Stars[1] += "*";
        else if (number < 31)
            Stars[2] += "*";
        else if (number < 41)
            Stars[3] += "*";
        else if (number < 51)
            Stars[4] += "*";
        else if (number < 61)
            Stars[5] += "*";
        else if (number < 71)
            Stars[6] += "*";
        else if (number < 81)
            Stars[7] += "*";
        else if (number < 91)
            Stars[8] += "*";
        else if (number < 101)
            Stars[9] += "*";

        for (int print = 0; print < 10; print++)
            System.out.println(Stars[print]);


        filescan.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Use a loop to generalize a repeating pattern

Comment: I think you are missing braces around your for loop. So number is just the last entry in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this-

```
while (filescan.hasNext()) {
    int num = filescan.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    list[i] = num;
}
```

should be this-

```
int i = 0, num;
while (filescan.hasNext()) {
    num = filescan.nextInt();
    list[i] = num;
    if(i == 100)
        break;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I indented it and it doesn't seem to make any difference. I also tried putting braces around the for loop. I'm getting the same results every time.

Comment: Does this part work correctly `for(int value : list)       System.out.println(value);` now??

Comment: That part worked correctly originally. It prints the "1-10 |" strings and 22 shows as 21-30 |* 
But I have about 20 different numbers in the txt file. It's only reading 22 and printing it 100 times. It's suppose to read and record each individual number and then print the asterisks for how many numbers fall in each range.

Comment: ok i think i figured out the error. wait, let me see what i can do with it.

Comment: @Kevin I am sorry about the indentation thing. I confused the language to be python as I primarily work on that. The problem, however, is with the way you have implemented the loop. Please check the edited answer.

Comment: That did it! I also had to put my star for loop in brackets to ensure that the if statements read each time number = list[st]; occurred. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kevin yes that correction was needed as well. I missed it but I am glad you could solve your problem. Welcome. :)